# Function to perform an arithmetic operation on two numbers and print the result

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written this function (in C++) to apply an arithmetic operation on two numbers and print the result.

```
void printResults(double a, double b, char c)
{
    double r;

    if (c=='+')
    {
        r = a + b;
    }
    else if (c == '-')
    {
        r = a - b;
    }
    else if (c == '*')
    {
        r = a * b;
    }
    else if (c == '/')
    {
        r = a / b;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid operator" << endl;
    }

    cout << a << " " << c << " " << " is " << r << endl;
}
```

but I am not happy as when condition fails I'll get an else output along with the last cout statement.

Can I make it better using IF or do I have to use SWITCH-CASE or take the cout statement inside of else?

I don't want to duplicate the last cout statement.

Comment: Please include a short description of your code, and edit the title to be a summary of that description. As it stands, we'd have to guess what this is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I think it's clear enough now.

Comment: Look up the command pattern.

Comment: I disagree that this lacks concrete context.  At one time, it was Unclear What You're Asking, but people edited it to include that information.  But what it still is is broken code.  The OP wants the code to behave differently, not to get a review of the code.  Telling the OP to put a `return` statement after the first `cout` would answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Fix the bug

The code as posted has this line:

```
cout << a << " " << c << " " << " is " << r << endl;
```

From the context, what was probably actually intended was more like this:

```
cout << a << " " << c << " " << b << " is " << r << endl;
```

### Use a `switch` where appropriate

The function does an operation based on the operation passed in.  That's an ideal case for a `switch` statement.  In addition to the clarity this brings to the human reader, it can also provide optimization possibilities for the compiler.

### Use a boolean flag

The code needs to treat an invalid operator differently from a valid one.  This suggests the use of a boolean flag.  I'd write `bool valid{true};` and then set it to false if an invalid operation is detected.  Then the printing can be wrapped in an `if..else` statement as `if (valid)...`

### Use meaningful variable names

The variable names `a`, `b`, and `c` are not at all descriptive. Better names might be `num1`, `num2` and `op`.  Doing so makes your code easier to read, understand and maintain.  Also, `printResults` is a very generic name and doesn't tell the reader much.

### Don't use `std::endl` if `'\n'` will do

Using `std::endl` emits a `\n` and flushes the stream.  Unless you really need the stream flushed, you can improve the performance of the code by simply emitting `'\n'` instead of using the potentially more computationally costly `std::endl`.

### Rethink the interface

Right now the code is hard-coded to only emit to `std::cout`.  It may be better to pass in a `std::ostream &` as a parameter to allow any output stream to be used.  Better still, leave the printing to the calling code as in the following suggestion.

### Use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

A C++17 feature is `std::optional` which is very useful for code like this.  Here's how it might be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

auto applyOperation(double first, double second, char op)
{
    bool valid{true};
    double result;

    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            result = first + second;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = first - second;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = first * second;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = first / second;
            break;
        default:
            valid = false;
    }
    return valid ? std::optional<double>{result} : std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
    constexpr double limit{2};
    constexpr double epsilon{0.5};
    constexpr char ops[]{'+','-','*','/','?'};
    for (const char op : ops) {
        for (auto first{-limit}; first < limit; first += epsilon) {
            for (auto second{-limit}; second < limit; second += epsilon) {
                auto result{applyOperation(first, second, op)};
                if (result) {
                    std::cout << first << " " << op << " " << second << " is " << result.value() << '\n';
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Invalid operator '" << op << "'\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `std::cerr` for error output

C++ provides a stream specifically for your error messages.  That's invaluable when you want to distinguish them from your normal output (if your program is writing to a file or pipe, for example):

```
else
{
    std::cerr << "Invalid operator: " << c << std::endl;
    return;
}

std::cout << a << " " << c << " " << b << " " << " is " << r << '\n';
```